# Java cannot find symbol - method hashset

Tags: java, hashset

I Have a problem with my java application, the class verhuur inherits from bedrijf. In Bedrijf i want to acces the method getBegintijd from the class verhuur although i get the error cannot find symbol - method getBegintijd.

Can somebody help me?

Class Bedrijf:

```
// instance variables
private HashSet<Verhuur> verhuur;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Bedrijf
 */
public Bedrijf()
{
    // initialise instance variables
    this.verhuur = new HashSet<Verhuur>();
}

/**
 * 
 */
public void add(Verhuur verhuur)
{
    this.verhuur.add(verhuur);
}

/**
 * 
 */
public void getBegintijd()
{
    System.out.println(verhuur.getBegintijd());
}
```

Class Verhuur

```
    // instance variabelen
private String Begintijd;
private String Eindtijd;
private int GebruikteBrandstof;
private boolean Schade;
private Boot boot;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Verhuur
 */
public Verhuur(String Begintijd, String Eindtijd, int GebruikteBrandstof, boolean Schade, Boot boot)
{
    // intialiseer instance variabelen
    this.Begintijd = Begintijd;
    this.Eindtijd = Eindtijd;
    this.GebruikteBrandstof = GebruikteBrandstof;
    this.Schade = Schade;
    this.boot = boot;
}

/**
Return de Begintijd
 */
public String getBegintijd()
{
    return Begintijd;
}

/**
Return de Eindtijd
 */
public String getEindtijd()
{
    return Begintijd;
}

    /**
Return de GebruikteBrandstof
 */
public int getGebruikteBrandstof()
{
    return GebruikteBrandstof;
}

    /**
Return de begintijd
 */
public boolean getSchade()
{
    return Schade;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`verhuur` is a `HashSet<Verhuur>`, so in order to call the `getBegintijd()` method of your `Verhuur` class you must obtain an element from the `HashSet`.

For example, the following code will call the `getBegintijd()` method for the first element returned by the `Set`'s iterator :

```
public void getBegintijd()
{
    if (!verhuur.isEmpty())
        System.out.println(verhuur.iterator().next().getBegintijd());   
    else
        System.out.println("empty set");
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks a lot! And how can i call more than just the first element?